# Python super init custom socket class

Tags: python, sockets, super

I would like to write a class which inherits the functionalities of `socket`.

So my code looks like this:

```
class walkie_talkie(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)):
    def __init__(self):
        self.BUFFERSIZE = 8192
        self.STATE = None
        self.IP = None                              # Server IP
        self.PORT = 5000
        self.NUMBER_OF_UNACCEPTED_CONNECTIONS = 1
        self.bytestream = None
        super().__init__()
```

And I use this class as:

```
from walkie_talkie import walkie_talkie

rpi1 = walkie_talkie()
```

So I thought using `super().__init__()` inherits functions of `socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)`

However, I receive this error:

```
File "...\lib\socket.py", line 151, in __init__
    _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Can someone tell me how to use the super function for that?

Comment: What does the first line of your code do?

Comment: A class can only inherit from another class, such as `socket.socket`.  You can't inherit from an *instance* of a class, as you're trying to do here.  The parameters you're trying to pass to `socket.socket()` should go in the `super().__init__()` line.

Comment: Also, you should have included the **full** error traceback and you would have seen *where* the error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

As [jasonharper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63378123/python-super-init-custom-socket-class/74833478#comment112069039_63378123) specified, a class can only inherit from another class, such as `socket.socket`. You can't inherit from an instance of a class, as you're trying to do here. The parameters you're trying to pass to `socket.socket()` should go in the `super().__init__()`.

```
class walkie_talkie(socket.socket):
    def __init__(self):
        self.BUFFERSIZE = 8192
        self.STATE = None
        self.IP = None  # Server IP
        self.PORT = 5000
        self.NUMBER_OF_UNACCEPTED_CONNECTIONS = 1
        self.bytestream = None
        super().__init__(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63378123/3) to the question [Python super init custom socket class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63378123/python-super-init-custom-socket-class) by the OP [V.Hunon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11158543/v-hunon) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>